# Form gets submitted twice with written ajax function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I wrote a JQuery AJAX submit script which would submit a form with the class ajax through AJAX and serialize it etc etc
Heres that script:

```
$("form.ajax").submit(function(){
   alert('a');
    var url = $(this).attr('action');
    if($(this).attr("element") != null)
    {
        var element = $(this).attr("element");
    }
    else if($(this).attr("element") == 'undefined')
    {
        var element = "render";
    }
    $("#"+element).html("<div id='loader'>Laden...<br /><img src=\"/site/templates/img/ajax-loader.gif\"/></div>");
    $.post(url, $(this).serialize(), function(data){

        $("#"+element).html(data);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Well, when i submit a form, any form with ajax class it gets submitted twice, i can see this in the network tab in the Chrome Console.

What is wrong, i dont get it ( i put alert ('a') there to check if it would pop up twice, but it does not).

Please help me?

EDIT:
The HTML, i posted it a couple of times before but okay here we go:

```
<form  class='ajax' element='make-payment' action='/statistieken/maak-betaling'  method='post'>
<input type='hidden' name='charity_id' value='1749'>
<li class='form-item'><label for='amount'>Bedrag:</label></li>
<li class='form-item'><input type='text' id='amount' name='amount' /></li>
<li class='form-item'><input type='submit' value='Betalen' /></li>
</form>
```

Greetings,
hawiak

Comment: this line `$("#"+element).html(data);` it doesnt know where `element` comes from since you declared it as var inside the if else statements. try doing a `console.log(element)` inside your $.post

mostly likely the output of that `console.log()` would be `undefined`

Comment: can you include your form full source so that it will be very clear

Comment: If I alert element it does alert the correct element 

<form class='ajax' action='/statistieken/goeddoel-overzicht/1749' method='post'><ul class='form-list'><li class='form-item'><label for='start_date' >Vanaf:</label></li><li class='form-item'><input type='text' id='start_date' value='2012-01-01' name='start_date' class='datepicker'></li><li class='form-item'><label for='end_date'>Tot:</label></li><li class='form-item'><input type='text' id='end_date' value='2012-10-19' name='end_date' class='datepicker'></li><li class='form-item'><input type='submit' value='Weergeven'></li></ul></form>

Comment: thats because you declared your `var element` inside your `if` `else` statements, that `var element` resides only within that scope

Comment: @ianace element has the value "make-payment" it got it from form class='ajax' element='make-payment' action='/statistieken/maak-betaling' method='post'>, sorry i was being unclear. it does work.

Comment: nope, from your code `element` should only be a 1.) element value from attribute `element` 2.) `render` and not `form class='ajax' element='make-payment' action='/statistieken/maak-betaling' method='post'>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
$("form.ajax").submit(function(){
   alert('a');
    var element;
    var url = $(this).attr('action');
    if($(this).attr("element") != null)
    {
        element = $(this).attr("element");
    }
    else if($(this).attr("element") == 'undefined')
    {
        element = "render";
    }
    $("#"+element).html("<div id='loader'>Laden...<br /><img     src=\"/site/templates/img/ajax-loader.gif\"/></div>");
    $.post(url, $(this).serialize(), function(data){

        $("#"+element).html(data);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: please provide the `html <form>` instead of making us guess it

Comment: `$("form.ajax")` this should select a form with class="ajax", that's nowhere in the given `<form>`, so it ignores your onSubmit event handler

Comment: check this out `http://jsfiddle.net/RQ3Qj/` if the url is alerted it means your selector is correct if not your `$("form.ajax")` is wrong or add `class="ajax"` to your form

Comment: Sorry i pasted the wrong one, i do have the ajax class in there... let me edit it